# I want to know if there is any possibility to remove pane options that occur after applying the indicators in advance trading view widget

Tags: charts, widget, trading, tradingview-api

I have been trying to hide the pane options by applying different disable features but failed to do so
[The marked section I want to remove through coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9ezF.png)

I have tried multiple props but nothing is reflecting and it is still showing the pane options
Following are the disable features that I have appiled
disabled_features: [
'use_localstorage_for_settings',
'header_widget',
'volume_force_overlay',
'timeframes_toolbar',
'edit_buttons_in_legend',
'property_pages',
'chart_zoom',
'volume_force_overlay',
'header_symbol_search',
'header_screenshot',
'header_compare',
'header_undo_redo',
'header_resizer',
'left_toolbar',
'display_market_status',
'header_fullscreen_button',
'header_settings',
'header_indicators',
'header_interval_dialog_button',
'header_symbol_info',
'header_chart_type',
'header_undo_redo',
'context_menus',
'border_around_the_chart',
'pane_context_menu',
'scales_context_menu',
'timeframes_context_menu',
'legend_context_menu',
'chart_property_page_background',
'go_to_date',
'adaptive_logo',
'widgetbar'
]

Answer (score 0):

No, not fron pinescript unfortunatly.

Comment: from any prop ? . I am using it in react